# How to suppress code parameter in Swashbuckle

Tags: swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, swashbuckle.examples

I have an Azure function app where Swashbuckle is configured and working with minimal configuration.

Swashbuckle is generating the web pages with parameters as desired, but the parameter `code` is added to every definition page.

How can I suppress the `code` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

[Configure Swashbuckle](https://github.com/vitalybibikov/AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle)

There is an option for this: `opts.AddCodeParameter = false;`